# objective c - Insert text description under Name of wifi On Setting Wifi of Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to insert description text like that:

[image]

Comment: so...what have you tried now?

Comment: like "Connect with WiFi..." ?

Comment: Thats just another label (with font size less) below the label displaying the name...

Comment: i want insert text description under name of wifi from Project Xcode

Comment: like "Connect with WiFi..." ? .. --> Yes, i want make like that